# Python type definitions with space or special chars

Tags: python, csv, header, typing

I have a python 3.8 routine intended to add typing to a CSV file with headers, as follows:

```
class Record(NamedTuple):
    """ Define the fields and their types in a record. """
    Category : str
    Item : str
    Serving Size :  str
    Calories : int
    SaturatedFat(%pctDaily) : int
    Sugars : int
    Protein : int

    @classmethod
    def _transform(cls: 'Record', dct: dict) -> dict:
        """ Convert string values in given dictionary to corresponding Record
            field type.
        """
        return {field: cls._field_types[field](value)
                    for field, value in dct.items()}
```

What I've discovered is that any header field containing spaces or special characters will error out with e.g.,

```
Saturated(%Fat) : float
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas how to solve this?
TIA,
Alex

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this is related to type annotations. Isn't this just the standard restriction on characters in Python names?

Comment: Those are not valid identifiers in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create a `NamedTuple` with illegal field names. Quote from the [documentation for `NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

> Any valid Python identifier may be used for a fieldname except for
>   names starting with an underscore. Valid identifiers consist of
>   letters, digits, and underscores but do not start with a digit or
>   underscore and cannot be a keyword such as class, for, return, global,
>   pass, or raise.

Do you need all the trappings of the `NamedTuple`? From what I see, having a custom dict-like will work well for you:

```
class Record:
    def __init__(self, record):
        self._fields = {}
        for k, t in {
            "Category": str,
            "Saturated(%Fat)": float
        }.items():
            self._fields[k] = t(record[k])

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._fields[key]
```

Note how the constructor knows which fields must be there. Use it like this:

```
record = Record({"Category": "foo", "Saturated(%Fat)": "5.5"})
record["Saturated(%Fat)"] # 5.5
```

This is a barebones solution and you may want to add other methods like `__len__()` or `items()`. Check out [Emulating Container Types](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) for your options.

Comment: "Trappings" indeed! So these are restrictions on NamedTuple, rather than the class fields themselves. Makes sense to me. Looks like those restrictions were in place for the pandas implementation of read_csv, which I believe was the reason I implemented the "import csv" approach instead. CSV files are a bear in almost any language, it helps a bunch to be able to strongly type the header columns, not having to edit what could be monster CSV files.

Comment: No, property names have a restricted set of characters which is why I recommended using a `dict` if you want to keep the original names.